Sous vide pouches puffed up - Is this product contaminated?
For years now, I have cooked a beef joint Sous Vide for 18-24 hours at 133F (57C) with a final sear in the oven. The meat is not blanched or pre-seared prior to Sous Vide cooking, just seasoned with salt.  The results have always been excellent. Upon removing from the Sous Vide bath, there is some juice in the bag but no major amount of expansion.
3 hours into this cook, I’ve noticed that the bags have swollen considerably, despite being packaged in same bags that I normally use with the same vacuum sealer. I always ensure the bags are a tight fit around the produce by squeezing air out as I vacuum seal them. The "Swelling" is not easy to see from the photos,but the bags have increased in volume by about 1cm.
I have checked the water with 2 different thermometers, and the temperature is OK.
The Internet is divided on this, some say it is OK at this temperature, others say it is contaminated. I notice that this meat was on offer, so I am thinking it was very close to “End of use by date” despite the packaging.
I’ll report back later upon opening the pack, but is this normal?



Update (After 24 hours):
The pouches have shrunk considerably and they are quite flexible with a little bit of meat juice as to be expected. There was no puffiness – the pouch was more saggy than bloated. No resistance was fetct when pushed,
On opening the pack, I immediately sniffed the contents and no “Off” odours were detected.  The beef when tasted, was melt in the mouth tender, juicy and delicious. I also carried out the undocumented “Cat test”, and our feline demolished the test sample in record time. (It is alleged that cats will not eat food that is “Off”, although I don’t think food safety bodies recognise this).
Naturally, I’ll leave it up to our guests if they wish to eat this joint, but from what I can tell it is perfectly fine. The mystery is why? It also begs the question as to what temperature the meat was really at during the initial cooking stages, as the air would insulate the meat from the water in the bath.
In future I think I’ll either increase the temperature to 60C, blanch the joint in boiling water for 1 minute to eradicate any surface bacteria or sear it just to be on the safe side.




Three hours at 59°C give me best results. More than that and meat turns mushy.

Why did you blank out the supermarket name? This isn't the BBC. I'm guessing ASDA.

Don't want to give the supermarket a bad name if there is nothing wrong.

If there’s gas from fermentation in the bag, there will be absolutely no doubt once you open it up and smell it. But I think it’s more likely just retained air. It can be difficult to get it all out with a suction-style sealer, and a small amount of residual air expands a surprising amount once heated to cooking temperature.

Plan of action - take the pouches out and see how resistant the bloating is to pressing. If they go down after a few minutes, it is probably just water vapour. The test will be opening the pouches as you say, if they smell bad something was fermenting.

Just open them. You do not have the equipment to determine the temperature of the gas (not water vapor) inside the pouch. “Pressing” them won’t tell you anything.

If there was fermentation though, surely there would be nowhere for the gaseous products to go other than to expand the pack? Steam will just recondense to water.

There’s no steam. Water boils at 100 Celsius. And a few minutes is not going to bring the temperature down significantly: yes, the thermal mass of the gas is negligible, but there’s a large hot piece of meat in the bag with it (giggity), keeping it warm even as the outside atmosphere tries to cool it down through the plastic.

If you reeeally want to do that experiment, submerge the bag in cool water; much more effective at cooling. It won’t tell you much, though. You already know there’s gas in there.

This is often from lactic acid bacterial growth, which can happen at temps below 60C and in long, low-temp cooks, if there is not good circulation, or if the bath is crowded.  You will know for sure if there is a funky smell when you open the bag.  This is why pre-searing your meat is a good idea (not to mention that a pre-sear also helps with better crust formation when you post-sear). Lactic acid bacterial growth is not harmful, but it is not pleasant either.

If it is lactic acid is it safe to eat though?

How would LAB grow on meat? Lactic acid fermentation consumes carbohydrates, of which there are very little in meat.

@Sneftel: first Google hit:https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0309174015001114

Yep, fair point. My intuition is that a non-inoculated piece of meat just isn’t going to get much proteolytic activity from LAB in 24 hours but I don’t have anything to back that up.

@Sneftel not uncommon in low temp, long sous vide cooks.  Thus the recommendation for a pre-sear or a dip in boiling water before bagging.
